# Can we characterise how correlated the expectation values associated with a pair of observables are?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, projection-operator

Consider a state $\rho$ and two observables $P$ and $Q$.

Is there a good way to characterise how correlated the associated expectation values are? Be it in terms of mutual information or something else.

As an example, if $\rho$ is a qubit and $P_i=|i\rangle\!\langle i|$ projectors onto the computational basis states, then we know that $P_0$ and $P_1$ are fully correlated, as $\langle P_1\rangle = 1- \langle P_0\rangle$. Knowing one tells the value of the other.
On the other hand of the spectrum, if $P_+\equiv |+\rangle\!\langle +|$, then knowledge of $\langle P_0\rangle$ imposes the bound
$$\frac12 - \sqrt{\langle P_0\rangle(1-\langle P_0\rangle)} \le \langle P_+\rangle \le \frac12 + \sqrt{\langle P_0\rangle(1-\langle P_0\rangle)}.$$
This can be seen starting from writing $\rho=\frac12(I+\sum_k c_k \sigma_k)$, observing that $\langle P_0\rangle = (1+c_z)/2$, $\langle P_+\rangle = (1+c_x)/2$, and $c_z^2+c_x^2\le1$, and thus concluding that $|c_x|\le \sqrt{1-c_z^2}$ with $c_z=2\langle P_0\rangle-1$.
Thus, in the case of $P_+$, we have a continuous freedom compatible with an observed value of $\langle P_0\rangle$, albeit with constrained bounds.

Can similar characterisations be made in the general case of an arbitrary pair of observables $P$ and $Q$?
To be more precise, I'm asking, given $\alpha=\langle P\rangle$, what is
$$\{\langle Q\rangle_\rho\equiv \mathrm{Tr}(\rho Q) : \rho\in\mathrm D(\mathcal X)\text{ such that } \langle P\rangle_\rho=\alpha\},$$
where $\mathrm D(\mathcal X)$ is the set of all states in the relevant Hilbert space $\mathcal X$.

Comment: Isn't this basically the commutator of the two observables? Also, have you looked at derivations of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

Comment: You might also find [entropic uncertainty relations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04857) interesting.

Comment: @DaftWullie I mostly understand the HUP, in its more general form, as the statement $\sigma_A\sigma_B\ge \lvert \langle AB\rangle - \langle A\rangle\langle B \rangle\rvert$. Sure it relates to this problem,  but how do you use this to find what you know about $\langle A\rangle$ given your knowledge of $\langle B\rangle$? I'm also not quite sure it holds in this form for general states. I mean I guess it does, but the derivation relies on the observation $\sigma_A^2=\| (A-\langle A\rangle I)|\psi\rangle\|^2$, so the proof might be a bit different for $\rho$ nonpure

Comment: @Rammus those are certainly interesting, but I still don't quite see the relation with what I'm asking. Those, as far as I understand, are different ways to formulate the HUP, which tells you, for a given state, how the variances/entropes of different observables relate to each other. Here I'm instead asking how observables' expvals are related to each other *independently* on the underlying state. In other words, I'm asking, given $\langle A\rangle$, what is $\{\langle B\rangle_\rho : \rho\}$ where $\rho$ ranges over all possible states compatible with the observation $\langle A\rangle$